# ScrollViewer not scrolling ItemsControl changes

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, scrollviewer

I am having a problem with a ScrollViewer in a modal dialog not changing scroll behavior when the ItemsSource of a ItemsControl inside the ScrollViewer changes.

When first creating the dialog the ScrollViewer's scrollbar behaves as expected with the size of the contents. When adding items to an ObservableCollection the ItemsControl is bound to the content changes but the ScrollViewer does not react to the change and activates the scrollbar.

Few items in ObservableCollection:

[image]

More items added to ObservableCollection :

[image]

After application restart:

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name ="Maingrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!--Style for RadButtons-->
            <Style TargetType="telerik:RadButton" x:Key="RadButtonStyle">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="95"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Style>
            <!--end of Style for RadButtons-->
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/PS.Common.Presentation;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--List-->
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="LeftScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BaysAndSystems, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Content="{Binding Item.NameAndReference}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </ScrollViewer>
    <!--Buttons-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <telerik:RadButton Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Copy}"   Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"     
                               CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource RadButtonStyle}" />
        <telerik:RadButton Content="{x:Static resx:Resources.Cancel}" Command="{Binding CopyCancledCommand}" 
                               CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource RadButtonStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

What can I do to get the ScrollViewer to react to the changed content?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScrollViewer` is in `Grid.Row="1"` which has a fixed height. Changed this grid's row height to `*`. It should work. Also you can try different values for `VerticalScrollBarVisibility`.

Comment: I have now tried setting the height to `*` and also setting `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Visible` but it has not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your row that holds your scrollviewer increases its height despite your definition of 200 px. Set it to "*" and set property `MaxHeight="200"` on your `Row` - it is going to be OK.

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="45" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where `Column` is. Can I set MaxHeight on a column?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Row.

Comment: I've now tried your code example but there is no difference.

Comment: Your first RowDefinition is redundant.
Try to modify your ItemsControl  Control Template in the way when your ScrollViewer wraps the ItemsPresenter.

Comment: When you change your ItemsControl by ListBox and remove ScrollViewer it works. Right?